# django REST filter query by foreign key lookup_field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I've got a time obj serialized to DRF.

model:

```
class Time(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='time_logs')
    amount = models.DurationField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

serializer:

```
class TimeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Time
        fields = ('__all__')
        extra_kwargs = {'date_created': {'read_only': True}, 'date_updated': {'read_only': True}}
```

viewset:

```
class UserTimeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TimeSerializer
    queryset = Time.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Time.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

urls

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'users/time', UserTimeViewSet)
```

this gives me an endpoint: `/users/time/{id}` where {id} is the Time obj id. when I tried to modify the endpoint to the same url route but instead pass it a user id as the arg (to get only that user's time) by overwriting `lookup_field` on the serializer and ViewSet, I'm either getting response errs or `{"detail":"Not found."}`

```
class UserTimeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TimeSerializer
    queryset = Time.objects.all().select_related('user')
    lookup_field = 'user'
```

also tried:

```
class UserTimeViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = TimeSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.kwargs['user']
        return Time.objects.filter(user=user)
```

how can I GET Time with a relationship to a user by user's id?

Comment: So, you want to input the **`user_id`** and retrieve the **`Time`** objects....right?

Comment: @JPG yes I want to input user_id and get Time objects back, filtered by user with that id

Comment: So, you need to return the time instance ***irrespective of the logged-in user*** ?

Comment: @JPG. yes. assuming client has a valid key and permissions to make their request, http://api.app.com/users/time/<user_id>/ should return the requested user's Time objs

Comment: What you mean by *" requested user's Time object"* ? at `/users/time/` end-point you will get the Time objects of the **logged-in** user

Comment: there is a foreign key relationship between User and Time models. we're talking about the queryset response to an API request, logged-in user is not relevant here.

Comment: I've added an answer. Please check it out

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understood correctly, this view class will do the magic

```
class UserTimeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TimeSerializer
    queryset = Time.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'user' # add "lookup_field" attribute

    # remove "get_queryset()" method
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Time.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: this works only if user has one time object. if the user has multiple times it will throw MultipleObjectsReturned get() returned more than one Time

Comment: Sorry... I forgot that point. I feel it's better to add a **filter** to your list api, ao that your requirement will work seamlessly

Comment: can you explain that more? you're recommending a separate custom filter? Time object queryset needs to be filtered by the lookup_field kwargs (in this case user id)

Answer (score 1):

JPG's other answer is a valid solution if the user only has one Time object. however, multiple objs will return a `MultipleObjectsReturned get() returned more than one Time` err

a solution for multiple objs was to convert the viewset into a ListAPIView:

views:

```
class UserTimeViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = TimeSerializer
    queryset = Time.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Time.objects.filter(user=self.kwargs['user'])
```

urls:

```
url(r'users/time/(?P<user>\d+)/$', UserTimeViewSet.as_view(), name='user_time'),
```